# How to uninstall Paragon NTFS trial

Tags: macos

i installed NTFS for Mac OS X (trial version) and removed it when it expired, but now every time I log on, I see this box that says "Your trial version has expired. To continue using the driver please buy it online" etc.

I removed the application and there's no entry under System Preferences -> Accounts -> Login Items for the application. I do have QuickApps (which lists all apps) under Login Items.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are all of the files removed?

They include:

```
/Applications/Paragon NTFS for Mac OS X /Manual.pdf
/Applications/Paragon NTFS for Mac OS X/Register NTFS for Mac OS X.app
/Library/Application Support/Paragon NTFS for Mac OS X/NTFS for Mac OS X.app
/Library/PreferencePanes/NTFSforMacOSX.prefPane
/System/Library/Filesystems/ufsd_NTFS.fs
/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.paragon.NTFS.trial.plist
/etc/mach_init_per_user.d/trial_expired_NTFS.plist
/sbin/fsck_ufsd_NTFS
/sbin/mount_ufsd_NTFS
/sbin/newfs_ufsd_NTFS
/usr/lib/libUFSDNTFS.dylib
/usr/sbin/fsctl_ufsd
/Library/Logs/ufsd.log
/tmp/ufsd.log
/usr/share/.intelligence
/Library/Receipts/$PRODUCT.pkg/Archive.bom
```

The PDFs and such don't matter, it's just for complete removals sake. It's likely only the `trial_expired_NTFS.plist` and `com.paragon.NTFS.trial.plist` files.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This was driving me nuts. I was missing the app support files.

Comment: I found this:`$ sudo find / -iname "*parago*" 
/Library/LaunchAgents/com.paragon-software.ntfs.notification-agent.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.paragon-software.pkg.ntfs.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.paragon-software.pkg.ntfs.plist
/private/var/folders/w8/m7lbtrjn5hx_wspgxtqt01680000gn/C/com.paragon-software.ntfs.installer
`

Answer (score 24):

In latest versions you can just do

```
System Preferences -> Paragon NTFS -> Settings tab -> Uninstall
```

Comment: This worked, except it left the Paragon Updater. I had to do this, then also remove:

    `/Library/Application Support/Paragon Software`
    `/Library/Application Support/Paragon Updater`

Comment: The location has slightly changed in Paragon NTFS 15: go to: `System Preferences | Paragon NTFS for Mac 15 | Preferences (⌘,) | Uninstall` (it may be protected by sys admin, so click the padlock in the bottom-left to unlock it).

Answer (score 4):

Go to System Preferences, open NTFS and press uninstall.

[image]

[image]

Comment: does not work anymore :(

Answer (score 3):

I deleted /Library/Application Support/Paragon NTFS for Mac OS X/ with all files in it. It worked, no more annoying popups.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem(s).  Mac OSX 10.5.8.  Try accessing the following file:

/username/Library/Preferences/loginwindow.plist

Edit with a text editor (some will not work -- "Text Wrangler" worked for me.  Make a duplicate file BEFORE editing (just in case).  Remove the unnecessary coding -- everything between the `<dict>` AND `</dict>` coding INCLUDING the `<dict>` and `</dict>` coding as well.

Example:

```
 <dict>
   <key>AliasData</key>
   <data>
   AAAAAADmAAMAAQAAfCWwgFwYSCsAAAAAAFe3TQBXumkAAMZc/kwA
   L1Jlc291cmNlcy9Hcm93bE1lbnUuYXBwAAATAAEvAP//AAA=
   </data>
   <key>Hide</key>
   <false/>
   <key>Path</key>
   <string>/Library/PreferencePanes/Growl.prefPane/Contents/Resources/NTFS.app</string>
  </dict>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running this script (if it is still available on your system and you haven't blindly deleted the folder based on other answers).

> sudo /Library/Application\ Support/Paragon\ Software/com.paragon-software.ntfs.uninstall

(Note: if you have Paragon EXTFS installed, replace `.ntfs.` in the above with `.extfs.`)

---

Result:

> unload kext: /Library/Extensions/lvm_for_mac.kext
>   remove: /Library/Extensions/lvm_for_mac.kext
>   remove: /Applications/Paragon ExtFS for Mac 11.app
>   remove: /Library/Application Support/Paragon Software/com.paragon-software.extfsd
>   remove: /Library/Application Support/Paragon Software/com.paragon-software.extfs.notification-agent.app
>   remove: /Library/Filesystems/ufsd_ExtFS.fs
>   unload kext: /Library/Extensions/ufsd_ExtFS.kext
>   remove: /Library/Extensions/ufsd_ExtFS.kext
>   unload daemon: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.paragon-software.extfs.loader.plist
>   remove: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.paragon-software.extfs.loader.plist
>   unload daemon: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.paragon-software.extfsd.plist
>   remove: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.paragon-software.extfsd.plist
>   unload agent: /Library/LaunchAgents/com.paragon-software.extfs.notification-agent.plist
>   /Library/LaunchAgents/com.paragon-software.extfs.notification-agent.plist: Could not find specified service
>   remove: /Library/LaunchAgents/com.paragon-software.extfs.notification-agent.plist
>   remove: /usr/local/sbin/fsck_ufsd_ExtFS
>   remove: /usr/local/sbin/mount_ufsd_ExtFS
>   remove: /Library/PreferencePanes/ParagonExtFS.prefPane
>   remove: /Library/Application Support/Paragon Software/com.paragon-software.extfs.uninstall

You'll find that the script also removes itself!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Just download the trial again from Paragon website and choose "Uninstall" on the installer launcher.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the method given shown by @Qianlu Li and open finder and hold shift+cmd+g and paste this

> /Library/Application Support/

delete the folders which belongs to Paragon.

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn out the package.( If it is deleted, download it again.)
2. One-click uninstall.

[image]

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “Turn out the package”, but the rest of your answer seems to be equivalent to [Alexis B.’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/101015/150988#1314310).

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled properly and also followed the guilelines, above, but it didn't solve my problem. I had to run

`sudo rm -rf /Library/Application Support/Paragon Software/`

Answer (score 0):

For version 15 you open the application (e.g. from the icon system menu bar, then the cog icon) and use the preferences (`NTFS for Mac -> Preferences -> General`). You may need to unlock the page with the lock icon in the bottom left and entering your password. There is an uninstall button on the same page.