# How can I completely remove all traces of Paragon NTFS for Mac 12 (Trial)?

Tags: macos, ntfs, finder, paragon

so I did something foolish and installed this software without fully reading the reviews about how bad it is. I did the free trial for Paragon NTFS for Mac 12. I ran the installation and after hitting the "restart" button, I got the grey screen with a circular ticker. This "loading" ticker just spun in circles for about 15 minutes, to which I assumed the install was a fail. I then pressed the power button until my Macbook restarted. Thankfully, my mac was not bricked, but it would no longer accept Fat 32 devices. I then ejected the installation folder and that caused Finder to lag. I killed the Finder task and after that, my flash drive was recognized perfectly. I am aware there is a similar question here about uninstalling Paragon, but I do not understand it. Can someone please give me a list of terminal commands to execute to completely wipe away the trial and any traces of it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've used Paragon for years without any issue & I can't find one bad review of it. Anyway, the installer is also an uninstaller.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361656/how-to-stop-ntfs-new-version-or-any-notification-for-that-matter

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/101015/how-to-uninstall-paragon-ntfs-trial?rq=1 If you're talking about not understanding this answer, I suggest going to Finder, press CMD + Shift + . and then to Keep pressing CMD + up arrow until you reach the root folder. Then go to all the folders and files mentioned in this answer. Press CMD + Shift + .  to hide the files again. I commented this, as the question required  terminal commands but this is a workaround.